# writing a wrapper in javascript for a java code

Tags: java, javascript, wrapper

I want to write a wrapper in javascript for a java class.

If I consider a simple java program

```
class Hello{

public static void main(String args [])
{
System.out.println("Welcome to java prog....");
}

}
```

How do I write a wrapper class in javascript for this.
I tried searching over internet but had no success.

It would also be helpful if somebody give pointer's as where to look at

Comment: javascript is unrelated to java.

Comment: DO you mean you want to simulate a Java class in JavaScript ?

Comment: unless you're asking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487908/how-can-i-use-javascript-in-java)

Comment: Basically I have client program which is written in java which receives message feeds from rabbitmq client. Now the idea is to wrap the client program in javascript and then redirect the message feeds to the browser. Does this make sense ?

Comment: @mohkhan : yes. reason I have explained above.

Comment: @TaylorFlores I think we can write a wrapper for a java api/function

Comment: @vijju you keep saying wrapper, do you mean a javascript library to run java programs?