# get function name in runtime and execute

Tags: java

Want to execute a function in runtime, which function name is got it from runtime:

```
public static void callClassname() throws Exception
{
    String[] getExecute =getInputdata.getEligibleColoumn();
    for(int i=0 ; i < getExecute.length ; i++)
    {
        getExecute[i] = getExecute[i].concat("()");String test = "classname." .concat(getExecute[i]);
        System.out.println("Test Passed:" + test);
    }
}
```

in the above code test will give the result `classname.functionname()`. I want to execute it or call it. Could you please help me how to do it, or any other better way? plz suggest.

Comment: Everything is executed at runtime.

Comment: if you have call this function in your main method or test annotation then this code will always run and if not then never

Comment: I don't see a way of doing that and `Classname.function()` works only for static functions. You could keep numbers or assign integers to denote methods and call them appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408837/convert-string-to-runtime-code-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem and to call instance methods is to use Java Reflection API

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is convert String to code at runtime and you could use BeanShell to achieve this.

You could download it from here:

http://www.beanshell.org/download.html

You could also check out Java Compiler API:

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-compiler-api.html