# I want to perform multiple mathematical operations within my string

Tags: java, android, string

```
 string input = "12+5-1";
```

Expected output would be: 16

The algorithm should identify the operators(+,-,*,/) and then do the operations one by one between the given numbers as inputs.

I initially created a string array

```
string[] strArrInput = input;
```

Somebody advised me however that I'm being inefficient that way because a string is already a character array. I need help with this logic.

EDIT:

By the way, I'm trying to make a scientific calculator that could do [PEMDAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: Ask the right questions and show us, what you have done so far!

Comment: Is efficiency really the issue here? If not, you should possibly focus on the most elegant solution.

Comment: You could parse this `String` as a javascript script (pun intended) and use a javascript engine like rhino or `ScriptEngine` to execute it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7487908/1065197

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in javascript engine for this..

```
    import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
    import javax.script.ScriptException;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine scriptEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            String expression = "12+5-1";
            System.out.println(scriptEngine.eval(expression));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol ScriptEngine

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple code using stack, look at this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Evaluate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=sc.next();
    Stack<Character> operator;
    Stack<Integer> operands;
    operands=new Stack<Integer>();
    operator=new Stack<Character>();
    int res=0,c;
    for(int i=0 ; i<input.length() ;i++){
        c =input.charAt(i);
        if(!isOperator(c)){
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
        }else{
            operator.push((char)c);
            operands.push(res);
            res=0;
            }
    }
    operands.push(res);
    int a,b;
    char op;
    for(; operands.size()>1 ;){
        a=operands.pop();
        b=operands.pop();
        op=operator.pop();
        operands.push(result(a,b,op));
    }

    System.out.println(operands);

}
public static boolean isOperator(int c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '\\';
}
public static int result(int a,int b,char c){
    if(c=='+')
        return a+b;
    if(c=='-')
        return b-a;
    if(c=='*')
        return a*b;
    else
        return b/a;
}

}
```

You can use something like this, I have not implemented operand priorities but i think you can do that now.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the String with the givn String functions. (indexOf,lastOf,split) But it is not that easy to write a algho who knows the mathematik.
I have done it once (without "()") but havnt the code to give it to you. 8[
I tell you what i have done:

I searched first for '*,/' 
eg

```
input=120-20*2+30;
```

split the string at the givn index

```
left=120-20; 
right=2+30;
```

at the left split i searcht the last +,- and on the right the first
split it again to the givn index
(leftRest=120;rightRest=+30)

now i take the left found Value -20 parse it to BigDecimal (because that will give u better results for comma values) and parse the right found Value to BigDecimal 2
now u can calculate

```
calcValue=-40=-20 * 2;
```

write the value back to the string, if the calcValue is not minus u have to write a + before; somting like this will do:

```
if(calcValue>0){
 setPlus="+";
}else{
 setPlus="";
}

input=leftRest+setPlus+Value+rightRest;
```

that give u:

```
 120-40+30
```

now u repead until there are no *,/
then u start searching +,-

If u Divide somthing with bigDecimal u have to say how many comma values u like to have ... otherwise it will throw an exeption for thinks like 1/3

if u want to do it with '()' u have to split the string at '(',')' first and do the math within, then write it back without '()'

hope i could help you a little, i think there are other ways to do so, but i only need 6h, fully drunk do write this code ^^

Stefan