# how to assign two characters to a char?

Tags: java, text, char

I am creating a singlish software.Don't think the word "Singlish" :-).

this is my code,

```
private void txt_titleKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 

char c = evt.getKeyChar();
         switch (c) {
            case 'a':
                txt_body.setText(txt_body.getText() + "අ");
                break;
            case 's':
                txt_body.setText(txt_body.getText() + "ස");
                break;
            }
 }
```

In this application ,when i am typing letter "a" program prints a specific character.I have two questions ,

1. if I press letter "a" the program prints the correct character ("අ") and                    also prints "a"
   (like this "අa"). 
   only I need "අ".how to prevent print "a".
2. If i typed "aa" ,I need to print a another character.so I tried

   ```
      case 'aa':
         txt_body.setText(txt_body.getText() + "ආ");
         break;
   ```

   but there is a error "Unclosed character literal"
   Is there any way to assign two characters to a char like in `javaScript`.

Comment: I wouldn't think the word "Singlish" had you not mentioned it. And I have no idea what it means anyway.

Comment: 1. you print   `(txt_body.getText() + "ආ"`  getText returns "a" because thats what the user pressed. 2. A Character can only hold one Character but you can use a Sting in a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think you should remove the last char that gets printed in order to get rid of the undesired char, i.e.

```
...
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
int index = txt_body.getText().lastIndexOf(c);
if(index >= 0) {
   txt_body.setText(txt_body.getText().substring(0, index));
}
     switch (c) {
...
```

As for the second question, the answer is : You can't. What Javascript does is silently converting your char to a string, which is what you should do in Java too.

Comment: Thanks.I tried your answer.but when i'm typing the first letter index is -1.

Comment: Can i use JavaScript to do this in java?

Comment: You are right, the example was missing a check on the index. Can you try it now? About Javascript, take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487908/how-can-i-use-javascript-in-java

Answer (score 0):

A character is a single letter, a data structure containing concatenation of characters is a string. In Java, you could do a switch statement on strings, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html), however, that being said, you have two problems:

1. The `txt_titleKeyTyped` event will fire at each key press, meaning that typing `aa` will fire the same event twice.
2. How do you intend to make your program differentiate between `aa` and two subsequent `a` characters?

You could have a timer which triggers after some time without key presses, say 500ms and tries to parse the string. You could then add `evt.consume();` at the end to ensure that the typed character does not end up within the text box.