# How Can we use WinJS with java script in java project?

Tags: javascript, winjs

I have one requirement for disable print screen capture in browser in my java web application.

I did lot of research and found that it is not possible.
But I found WinJS java script in which it provide this functionality of disabling screen capture.

Now I am not sure whether this WinJS can be use in java script in my java web project or not ?If yes than how ?

I have tried to implement this in my java project but no SUCCESS !!!

Comment: Maybe because JavaScript has nothing to do with Java?

Comment: @Justinas, what you mean to say ?

Comment: You try to use code from one language (and it's library) in other language. Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487908/how-can-i-use-javascript-in-java

Comment: hmmm...@Justinas, yup i already know that but I think its not related to my question !!!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can not implement Javascript in java, these are 2 different things.

WinJS is intended to be used into windows applications created in html/css/javascript, not Java applications

Maybe there's a Java aproach to fit your requirements, but i dont think so. The print screen funcitionality is embebbed in the operative system, so i think is hard to disable this.

Comment: Thank... That's a short and sweet answer

Comment: I hope that this answer would help you, I can't help you with anything more. So probably you would need to inform that the requirement is not possible! If you consider this answer as the correct one, please mark it as correct. Good luck! If you find some way to do it, please post it as an answer, probably that can help anybody else with this issue in the future